# What is the best data type to store boolean values in a database

Tags: database, database-design, rdbms, sqldatatypes

What is the best data type to store boolean values in a database? which is supported by mostly used RDBMS types such as Mysql,oracle,postgres,mssql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use TINYINT or bit datatype

Comment: thanks I;l be using TINYINT as it is supported by many data storages

Answer (score 2):

If the DBMS supports a real `boolean` type (e.g. PostgreSQL) then use that. If it doesn't I usually prefer an integer value combined with a check constraint that ensures that only `0` and `1` can be stored. In my experience it also makes sense to define the column as `NOT NULL` as well. Having a `NULL` value for a boolean is always somewhat confusing.

You won't find a *single* datatype that works for all DBMS. I would always use the "best" one that the DBMS offers.